# What is the difference between Enum and Constant Java class?

Tags: java, enums

I am getting confused regarding `Enum`.

Where and how to use `Enum`?

If I will use `Enum` instead of `constant` then what could be the benefit?

Could someone please explain to me?

Comment: What is "constant class"?

Comment: public ApplicationConstant{                                    private static final String male="MALE";   }

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the advantage of a Java enum versus a class with public static final fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969690/whats-the-advantage-of-a-java-enum-versus-a-class-with-public-static-final-fiel) or [this](Static String constants VS enum in Java 5+) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229297/java-enumerations-vs-static-constants).

Answer (score 1):

The primary advantage is type safety. With a set of constants, any value of the same intrinsic type could be used, introducing errors. With an enum only the applicable values can be used.

Answer (score 1):

An Enum class is used to specify a range of constants that will be frequently used within an application.

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html:

> You should use enum types any time you need to represent a fixed set of constants.
>   Common examples include compass directions (values of NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, and WEST) and the days of the week.

A constant class (assuming this is what you are talking about), is really specified for one solid object that you wouldn't change. Technically, an Enum class is a constant class with more definitions, but an advantage to an Enum class is [some pre-defined functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) that you would have to define in your own constant class. However, you should also note that this may be overkill for small, singleton examples.

Additionally, Enum classes are type-safe, whereas static fields aren't. Compile time error checking is now possible, versus the run-time potential errors that will occur with a constant class. This furthermore improves readability, because instead of having errors where an index of a list of constants is unavailable. This is all well explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709175/what-are-enums-and-why-are-they-useful?rq=1), by the current best answer.

Comment: suppose same compass property I will use inside a constant .then why should I use Enum.

Comment: Thanks I got my ans.now I am cleared.

Comment: IF you are clear then you should accept and/or upvote answers

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 8.0 the keyword "constant" does not exist.

If you mean "const":
This keyword is in the known keywords in Java (from the beginning until today - 8.0),
but it has no use and any compiler shouldn't compile if it find's this keyword.

Enumerations:
Use them when you have specific logical values and don't want to handle them in String,
like:

```
public enum AcceptableColours {
    BLACK,
    WHITE,
    GREY
}
```

It's much safer during development time to match enum values

```
AcceptableColours currentColour = object.getColour;
if (currentColour == acceptableColours.BLACK) {
    // do something
} else if (currentColour == acceptableColours.WHITE) {
    // do something different
}
```

than to match string values

```
AcceptableColours currentColor = object.getColour;
if (currentColor.equals("black")) {
    // do something
} else if (currentColor.equals("white")) {
    // do something different
}
```

... imagine huge applications with much more variations on enum values (like banking software, insurance software, ...), where it's much easier to misspell some string values,
and voilà, happy debugging...